# Conditions for global invertibility of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $U$ be open and convex, $f:U \rightarrow \Bbb R^n$ continuously differentiable, where $\|Df(x)-Id\| < 1$, for all $x \in U$.

Then, $f$ is injective on $U$ (thus, $f:U \rightarrow f(U)$ is globally invertible.)

**Attempt at a solution:**

Let $g(x) = f(x) - x$ and choose $a,b \in U$ where $a \neq b$.

\begin{align}
||g(b)-g(a)|| &=||f(b)-b- \left(f(a)-a) \right)|| \\ 
&= \left|\left|\int_{0}^{1} \left[\frac {d}{dt}\left(\left(1-t\right)a + tb-f\left(\left(1-t\right)a+tb\right)\right) dt \right]\right|\right| \\ 
&\le\left|\left|\int_{0}^{1} \left[\left(b-a\right)-Df\left(\left(1-t\right)a + tb\right)\left(b-a\right) dt \right]\right|\right| \\
&\le\left|\left|b-a\right|\right|\int_{0}^{1} \left|\left|Id-Df\left(\left(1-t\right)a + tb\right)\right|\right| dt \lt\left|\left|b-a\right|\right|\int_{0}^{1}dt
\end{align}

Thus, $$||g(b)-g(a)||\lt\left|\left|b-a\right|\right|$$

It is at this point I do not come any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the reverse triangle inequality, if $a \neq b$ then
$$
\|f(b) - f(a)\| = \|b - a + g(b) - g(a)\| \geq \bigl|\|b - a\| - \|g(b) - g(a)\|\bigr| > 0.
$$

Comment: Which shows that $f(a) \neq f(b)$ and thus $f$ is injective. Beautiful, thank you.